# I need Macros to run constantly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create automatic email reminders to be sent when a due date is close. I need it to run constantly so it produces the reminders as time goes by and as cells get updated without having to re-run the code

```
Public Sub CheckAndSendMail()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2018/11/22
    Dim xRgDate As Range
    Dim xRgSend As Range
    Dim xRgText As Range
    Dim xRgDone As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xLastRow As Long
    Dim vbCrLf As String
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim xRgDateVal As String
    Dim xRgSendVal As String
    Dim xMailSubject As String
    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRgDate = Application.InputBox("Please select the due date column:", "KuTools For Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xRgDate Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRgSend = Application.InputBox("Please select the recipients?email column:", "KuTools For Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xRgSend Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRgText = Application.InputBox("Select the column with reminded content in your email:", "KuTools For Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xRgText Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xLastRow = xRgDate.Rows.count
    Set xRgDate = xRgDate(1)
    Set xRgSend = xRgSend(1)
    Set xRgText = xRgText(1)
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    For i = 1 To xLastRow
        xRgDateVal = ""
        xRgDateVal = xRgDate.Offset(i - 1).Value
        If xRgDateVal <> "" Then
        If CDate(xRgDateVal) - Date <= 7 And CDate(xRgDateVal) - Date > 0 Then
            xRgSendVal = xRgSend.Offset(i - 1).Value
            xMailSubject = xRgText.Offset(i - 1).Value & " on " & xRgDateVal
            vbCrLf = "<br><br>"
            xMailBody = "<HTML><BODY>"
            xMailBody = xMailBody & "Dear " & xRgSendVal & vbCrLf
            xMailBody = xMailBody & "Text : " & xRgText.Offset(i - 1).Value & vbCrLf
            xMailBody = xMailBody & "</BODY></HTML>"
            Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With xMailItem
                .Subject = xMailSubject
                .To = xRgSendVal
                .HTMLBody = xMailBody
                .Display
                '.Send
            End With
            Set xMailItem = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    Next
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Running a macro "constantly" is a bit of a misnomer in this context I think. Is your workbook always open and never closed, or if not when is it opened by a user? How often is the data in the workbook updated and is it updated automatically (via links or connections), by user input, or by another macro? These details will help guide the answer we can recommend.

Comment: You have to have a trigger for the macros. Either a UI element event, a worksheet change event, workbook open, or timer. In your case, I think a `Worksheet_Change` event would do.